# $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ cannot possess a non-degenerate alternative bilinear pairing

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Why $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ doesn't have non-degenerate alternative bilinear pairing ?

Here,for abelian group $A$, bilinear pairing $A×A\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}, (a,a)\mapsto 〈a,a〉$ is called non-degenerate if only if $\forall a\in A, 〈a,b〉=0 \implies b=0$.

General theory implies abelian group $A$ which has non-degenerate alternative bilinear pairing should take the form $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}×\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$. So $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ cannot possess a non-degenerate bilinear pairing. But my question is, can we prove that without big tools ?

Comment: Surely there exists non-degenerate bilinear pairings. Such as $\langle \overline{m},\overline{n}\rangle=(mn/4)+\Bbb{Z}$. The extra requirement of the pairing to be *alternative* must play a role.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding that key word to the title as well. Lest future readers are instantly puzzled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\langle\ ,\ \rangle:\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_4\to\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ is bilinear and alternative, then (by the rule $\langle a,b\rangle=-\langle b,a\rangle$)
$$\langle\overline{1},\overline{1}\rangle=-\langle\overline{1},\overline{1}\rangle.$$
It follows that  $\langle\overline{1},\overline{1}\rangle$ equals either $0+\Bbb{Z}$ or $(1/2)+\Bbb{Z}$. On the other hand, by bilinearity, for all intergers $m,n$ we must have
$$\langle\overline{m},\overline{n}\rangle=mn\langle\overline{1},\overline{1}\rangle.$$

Putting these together implies that for all $a\in\Bbb{Z}_4$ the pairing $\langle a,\overline{2}\rangle$ is an even multiple of $\langle\overline{1},\overline{1}\rangle$, i.e. equal to zero.

Comment: Could you tell me why the rule $(alb)=-(bra)$ holds ?

Comment: @Pont What's your definition of *alternative bilinear pairing*? I assumed it means that $\langle a,b\rangle=-\langle b,a\rangle$ for all $a,b$. In some contexts a bilinear form is called *alternating*, if $\langle a,a\rangle=0$ for all $a$.

Comment: Of course, if your definition flat out requires that $\langle\overline{1},\overline{1}\rangle$ vanishes, then the argument is even simpler.